# Is there a way to change the Windows Insider text/watermark?

Tags: windows, windows-insider, windows-11-preview

I was wondering if I could change the Watermark text or add text to it. As an example some builds have the "do not take screenshots" text above the watermark. Could I add custom text or something like that? Is it some Registry value or is it build specific? (Hard-Coded)

[image: Watermark]

[image: What I am referring to]

There is also text which can be placed at the top eg.
[image: What I am referring to]

Comment: IIRC, the watermark is taken from Registry keys

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge (as a Windows Insider user) this is hard coded and indicates that the version being used will expire at some point (after, of course) the next Insider version.

You cannot modify this text so far as I know.